# Using a resultProxy object in sqlalchemy as a subquery

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I want to convert a resultproxy object into a subquery for use with an ORM query. What's the procedure to do this? I can't really find any examples.

Answer (score 3):

A result proxy is something that you get when a SELECT statement is passed to the database and executed - at that point, there's no more "query" so in a literal sense, a result proxy isn't a subquery.  However, that SELECT statement which you have executed, can instead *not* be executed and passed into another query as a subquery pretty easily:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String)

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

sess = Session(e)

# test data.
sess.add_all([A(data="d%d" % i) for i in range(10)])
sess.commit()

# a query.
subq = sess.query(A.id).filter(A.data.in_(["d3", "d4", "d5"]))

# execute subquery, gives us a list of tuples
list_of_tuples = subq.all()

# execute subquery via Core, gives us a ResultProxy
result_proxy = sess.execute(subq)

# inject subq into another Query as a subquery()
q = sess.query(A).filter(A.data.in_(subq.subquery()))
a_from_subquery = q.all()
```